# Cannot open include file: 'jni.h': No such file or directory

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface, header-files

I am trying to use the C++ version of [voce](http://voce.sourceforge.net/) voice recognition API. It is an API built in Java, with support to C++ as well. However, whenever I am trying to execute it, I am getting the error

```
C:\Users\yohan\Documents\Extra C++ Libs\Voice Recognition - Voce API\voce-0.9.1\src\c++\voce.h:34: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jni.h': No such file or directory
```

This is my .pro content

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-04-26T12:59:05
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Tired
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32

LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_calib3d240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_contrib240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_core240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_features2d240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_flann240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_highgui240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_imgproc240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_objdetect240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_video240.lib

HEADERS +=
```

This is the code for **Main.cpp**

```
#include "C:/Users/yohan/Documents/Extra C++ Libs/Voice Recognition - Voce API/voce-0.9.1/src/c++/voce.h"

int main()
{


}
```

A small part of the code of **voce.h** is given below

```
#ifndef VOCE_H
#define VOCE_H

// This file contains a C++ interface for Voce's Java functions.  All of 
// the Java methods in Voce's API are instance methods, so we don't need 
// to handle class methods here.  For documentation on the specific 
// functions, refer to the API documentation for the Java source.

#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/// The namespace containing everything in the Voce C++ API.
namespace voce
{
#ifdef WIN32
const std::string pathSeparator = ";";
#else
const std::string pathSeparator = ":";
#endif

    /// Contains things that should only be accessed within Voce.
    namespace internal
    {
        /// Global instance of the JNI environment.
        JNIEnv* gEnv = NULL;

        /// Global instance of the Java virtual machine.
        JavaVM *gJVM = NULL;

//Code Continues..........................................
```

How can I get rid of this error? I am using QT, the latest version which use the Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

Comment: Silly question but do you have a JDK installed?

Comment: @john: Of course I do :)

Comment: Does "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/" contain `jni.h`?

Comment: Are you building it through qmake or through the Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: @Yohan OK but we do have to ask these questions.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the path in the two 'INCLUDEPATH += C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/' entries?  Just wondering if the space in Program Files is causing a problem.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer: QT Creator.. I am using it

Comment: @spdaley: Quoting? No..How to do it in the exact way?

Comment: @Yohan: I've never actually worked with this before but if some of the other SO questions around this stuff are correct, you just put " around the path ... so INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Java/..."

Comment: @spdaley: Great. Thank you. Please provide your comment as the answer.

Comment: For the project I was trying to build (Sleuthkit), I just needed to add an environment variable JDK_HOME and point it to the JDK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should quote the parts of the INCLUDEPATH that contain spaces. Instead of doing:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32
```

You should probably be doing:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32"
```

Comment: Locate jni.h returns me nothing. I have java 1.7 installed on Ubuntu 13.04 machine.